# django throwing errors about template having to do with links

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am a newbie with Django. I'm following the tutorial [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/18/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-3.html):

We just got to the part with templates. So I have a template now, base.html:

```
{% load static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Django Boards{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ol class="breadcrumb my-4">
        {% block breadcrumb %}
        {% endblock %}
      </ol>
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a homepage that extends base.html:

```
{% extends base.html %}
{% block title %}Boards{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumb %}
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Boards</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
      <tr>
        <th>Board</th>
        <th>Posts</th>
        <th>Topics</th>
        <th>Last Post</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for board in boards %}
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="{% url 'board_topics' board.pk %}">{{ board.name }}</a>
            <small class="text-muted d-block">{{ board.description }}</small>
          </td>
          <td class="align-middle">0</td>
          <td class="align-middle">0</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
{% endblock %}
```

I have a page called topics.html that does not (yet) extend base.html:

```
{% load static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ board.name }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ol class="breadcrumb my-4">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Boards</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">{{ board.name }}</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I have a test page, tests.py:

```
# from django.test import TestCase

# Create your tests here.
from django.urls import reverse
from django.urls import resolve
from django.test import TestCase
from .views import home, board_topics
from .models import Board

class HomeTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.board = Board.objects.create(name='Django', description='Djano Board')
        url = reverse('home')
        self.response = self.client.get(url)

    def test_home_view_status_code(self):
        self.assertEquals(self.response.status_code, 200)

    def test_home_url_resolves_home_view(self):
        view = resolve('/')
        self.assertEquals(view.func, home)  

    def test_home_view_contains_link_to_topics_page(self):
        board_topics_url = reverse('board_topics', kwargs={'pk': self.board.pk})
        self.assertContains(self.response, 'href="{0}"'.format(board_topics_url))

class BoardTopicsTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Board.objects.create(name='Django', description='Django board.')

    def test_board_topics_view_success_status_code(self):
        url = reverse('board_topics', kwargs={'pk': 1})
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_board_topics_view_not_found_status_code(self):
        url = reverse('board_topics', kwargs={'pk': 99})
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 404)

    def test_board_topics_url_resolves_board_topics_view(self):
        view = resolve('/boards/1/')
        self.assertEquals(view.func, board_topics)

    def test_board_topics_view_contains_link_back_to_homepage(self):
        board_topics_url = reverse('board_topics', kwargs={'pk':1})
        response = self.client.get(board_topics_url)
        homepage_url = reverse('home')
        self.assertContains(response, 'href="{0}"'.format(homepage_url))
```

When I go to the command line and run test, I get these error messages:

```
(venv_two) C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\myproject2>python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
....EEE
======================================================================
ERROR: test_home_url_resolves_home_view (boards.tests.HomeTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\myproject2\boards\tests.py", line 14, in s
etUp
    self.response = self.client.get(url)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\test\cli
ent.py", line 527, in get
    response = super().get(path, data=data, secure=secure, **extra)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\test\cli
ent.py", line 339, in get
    **extra,
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\test\cli
ent.py", line 414, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\test\cli
ent.py", line 495, in request
    raise exc_value
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\core\han
dlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\core\han
dlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\core\han
dlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\myproject2\boards\views.py", line 9, in ho
me
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'boards': boards})
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\shortcut
s.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=usi
ng)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\test\uti
ls.py", line 96, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\loader_tags.py", line 127, in render
    compiled_parent = self.get_parent(context)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\loader_tags.py", line 117, in get_parent
    raise TemplateSyntaxError(error_msg)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid template name in 'extend
s' tag: ''. Got this from the 'base.html' variable.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_home_view_contains_link_to_topics_page (boards.tests.HomeTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\myproject2\boards\tests.py", line 14, in s
etUp
    self.response = self.client.get(url)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\test\cli
ent.py", line 527, in get
    response = super().get(path, data=data, secure=secure, **extra)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\test\cli
ent.py", line 339, in get
    **extra,
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\test\cli
ent.py", line 414, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\test\cli
ent.py", line 495, in request
    raise exc_value
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\core\han
dlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\core\han
dlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\core\han
dlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\myproject2\boards\views.py", line 9, in ho
me
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'boards': boards})
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\shortcut
s.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=usi
ng)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\test\uti
ls.py", line 96, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\loader_tags.py", line 127, in render
    compiled_parent = self.get_parent(context)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\loader_tags.py", line 117, in get_parent
    raise TemplateSyntaxError(error_msg)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid template name in 'extend
s' tag: ''. Got this from the 'base.html' variable.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_home_view_status_code (boards.tests.HomeTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\myproject2\boards\tests.py", line 14, in s
etUp
    self.response = self.client.get(url)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\test\cli
ent.py", line 527, in get
    response = super().get(path, data=data, secure=secure, **extra)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\test\cli
ent.py", line 339, in get
    **extra,
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\test\cli
ent.py", line 414, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\test\cli
ent.py", line 495, in request
    raise exc_value
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\core\han
dlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\core\han
dlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\core\han
dlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\myproject2\boards\views.py", line 9, in ho
me
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'boards': boards})
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\shortcut
s.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=usi
ng)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\test\uti
ls.py", line 96, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\loader_tags.py", line 127, in render
    compiled_parent = self.get_parent(context)
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myproject2\venv_two\lib\site-packages\django\template
\loader_tags.py", line 117, in get_parent
    raise TemplateSyntaxError(error_msg)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid template name in 'extend
s' tag: ''. Got this from the 'base.html' variable.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.065s

FAILED (errors=3)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Can anyone tell me what these errors mean please? I thought I followed the instructions in the tutorial exactly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `extends` call is missing quotations. You have: `{% extends base.html %}` and you need `{% extends 'base.html' %}`.  Also, once you have the quotes, make sure that your file path is indeed just `base.html`.